# How to access fields declared inside anonymous object?

Tags: java, visibility, inner-classes, anonymous-class

Java lets you declare new fields inside anonymous classes, but I can't figure out how to access them from outside, even setting them to public doesn't let me.

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object o = new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       };
       System.out.println(o.x);
   }
}
```

I get this compiler error:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable x
location: class java.lang.Object
       System.out.println(o.x);
                           ^
1 error
```

Why?

Comment: This aint JavaScript man :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why?

It's because `Object` is the static type of the variable `o`, and `Object` doesn't have the property `x`. The following fails to compile for the exact same reason:

```
public class X {
  public int x;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object o = new X();
    o.x = 3;
  }
}
```

Hopefully, your Java intuition is right on this example and you *expect* this to fail. So just transplant that intuition to your example.

> How to access fields declared inside anonymous object?

Same way as you'd access `x` in my example: reflection.

```
Object o = new X();
o.getClass().getField("x").setInt(o, 3);
```

> Why does it let me make public fields if I can't use them?

If it didn't let you make public fields, even reflection wouldn't work for you, at least not as simply as above.

Comment: in the second example it is possible with `X o = new X();` or with cast `((X) o) .getClass() ... ` also need to catch some checked exceptions for reflection

Comment: Possible, but irrelevant because it isn't applicable for OP.

Answer (score 3):

You could only do that by reflection. The class has no name, so you had to declare the variable `o` as an `Object`, and `Object` does not have that member. In other words, *don't do this*.

Comment: Then howcome unused variables are a compile error? It's easier to not prohibit that yet Java does it.

Comment: Unused variables are *not* a compile error by the Java Language Specification. What an IDE is configured to report as an error has nothing to do with Java the language.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Oops. I meant, unreachable lines of code cause compile errors. Also it's easier not to have types, so I wouldn't argue that Java is in the business of making something so just because it's easier to implement.

Comment: I deleted my comment because it became nonsense when another comment was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You could acces the field by reflection:

```
    Object o = new Object() {
       public int x = 0;
       {
           System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           System.out.println("x: " + x++);
       }
   };
   System.out.println(o.getClass().getField("x").get(o));
```

Better Style would be to name the class and use it as variable type, if you want to access field:

```
    class MyObject {
       public int x = 0;
       {
           System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           System.out.println("x: " + x++);
       }
   }
   MyObject o = new MyObject();
   System.out.println(o.x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could access it directly on the anonymous class creation expression:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       }.x);
   }
}
```

But then, you can't otherwise use the object created anymore, so it's kinda useless.

Answer (score 0):

Define an internal class that extends `Object` (in your specific case you should not write `extends Object` as it is done anyway. In your class, define your fields and than access them by reference of your type.

Example:

```
void func() {
     class MyInt extends Integer {
         boolean isSane = true;
     }
     MyInt intInstance = new MyInt();
     if (intInstance .isSane) {
         System.out.println("sane integer");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also after Java 10 you can use 'var' magic (Local Variable Type-Inference)

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Object o = new Object() {
       var o = new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       };
       System.out.println(o.x);
   }
}
```