# How to access fields declared inside anonymous object without reflection?

Tags: java, types, inner-classes, anonymous-class

It's possible to make anonymous classes have new fields in Java:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object o = new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       };
       System.out.println(o.x);
   }
}
```

But they can't be accessed in this example, because `o` is of type `Object`:

```
$ javac A.java && java A
A.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable x
location: class java.lang.Object
       System.out.println(o.x);
                           ^
1 error
```

Note that `o` is actually not an `Object`, it's an instance of a different class extending `Object`. This class has one public field `x`. Does this class have a name? How can I make `o` be the proper type so I can get access to `o.x`? (Note that [it's possible to do this with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490458/2213023), but I want to do it statically).

Comment: I don't think you can without using an interface.

Comment: Have you considered declaring the class within the method? At that point you could get at it...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes I have, but this question is about how to do it without doing that. It seems like it should be possible, just not obvious how.

Comment: @Dog: *Why* do you think it should be possible? The only way of expressing a variable of that type is by giving the type a name. It doesn't surprise me at all that this can't be done, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, newacct made it work for one field, so surely there is some syntax to make it work for multiple. Even if there is no special syntax for this, it seems like there is a naming convention for anonymous classes (`A$1` for the first, `A$2` for the second, and so on).

Comment: @Dog: No, there's no "surely" about it. newacct's answer isn't just limited to a field - it's also limited to an instance that you don't want to do *anything* else with. This is simply not something anonymous inner classes were designed for.

Comment: @JonSkeet: dudebro's answer proves you wrong...

Comment: @Dog: Not at all. That's relying on a compiler implementation detail *and* it requires recompilation. It's horribly brittle. **Just don't do it.** Give it up - create a named type instead. You still haven't said anything about *why* you want to work against the language in this way.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was trying to implement a singleton in a certain way... kind of irrelevant to the post, i just wanted to understand anonymous classes.

Comment: @Dog: So there's nothing that you really needed this feature for, right? And I can't remember ever hearing anyone else asking for it either. So you shouldn't be surprised that it's not something the language supports.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I was trying to implement a singleton by making a static anonymous class which represents state inside an interface so that the static function objects inside the interface can use its private variables without other classes outside the interface having access to them: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/26263/25157

Comment: Seems like a very odd use of interfaces to me, to be honest. Trying to use Java as a functional language has various problems at the moment - I would personally wait until Java 8 comes out, or use a different language if you want things to feel functional. It doesn't *at all* surprise me that a situation so far removed from the normal uses of interfaces would cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object o = new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       };
       //System.out.println(((A$1)o).x);
   }
}
```

compile once

```
$ java A.java
```

uncomment print line

recompile & run

```
$ java A.java && java A
x: 0
x: 1
2
```

Comment: howcome it needs to be compiled twice?

Comment: @Dog: Because the first time it will create an `A$1.class` file, and then second time it will consume it, while also recreating it. This is really brittle, and I'd *strongly* suggest you don't do it.

Comment: Don't try this at home!

Answer (score 3):

This class does have a name. It's `A$1`. However, you can't access this at compile time (the compiler creates `A$1` for you). Thus, you can't access the field without reflection.

If you're in Eclipse, you can use **Source** menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>) → **Convert Anonymous Class to Nested** to convert it to a "real" class automatically.

Alternatively, you could have:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       I o = new I() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
           public int getX() { return x; }
       };
       System.out.println(o.getX());
   }
   interface I {
       public int getX();
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's a *really evil way* to accomplish this that you *should not do*:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Object o = new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }

           public Object clone() {
               // BAD BAD BAD
               return x;
           }
       };
       try {
           System.out.println(o.clone());
       } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
           assert false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yup.  There really isn't a way to do it without changing the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could access it directly on the anonymous class creation expression:

```
class A {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(new Object() {
           public int x = 0;
           {
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
               System.out.println("x: " + x++);
           }
       }.x);
   }
}
```

But then, you can't otherwise use the object created anymore, so it's kinda useless.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not a C#, if I'am not mistaken such syntax sugar is allowed there. You can have a look at sun.reflect.MagicAccessorImpl. But this class is not a common practice. Used only for auto generated code. If you extend MagicAccessorImpl JVM will not perform field access level check. So you can do thing like this:

```
// ----- A.java -----
class A {
    private int privateField = 5;
}

// ----- B.java -----
class B extends sun.reflect.MagicAccessorBridge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.privateField = 10;
        System.out.println(a.privateField);
    }
}

// ----- MagicAccessorBridge.java -----
package sun.reflect;

public class MagicAccessorBridge extends MagicAccessorImpl {
    // Since MagicAccessorImpl is package-private, we'll make a public bridge
}
```

[Taken from here](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132703/)